# adding / removing a class from an ember input

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Using ember 1.0 and handlebars 1.0

I want to present an ember input as disabled until the user presses the edit button. I have managed to get the functionality working at the expense of code duplication.

```
{{#if isEditing}}
  {{input type="text" value=firstName class="form-control" placeholder="First name" }}
{{else}}
  {{input type="text" value=firstName class="form-control" placeholder="First name" disabled=""}}
{{/if}}
```

just wondering if there was a better way ..

thanks

Comment: The title of this question is misleading. This isn't about adding classes to an ember input, but about disabling an ember input.

Comment: The end comment by selvagsz addresses the title though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of disabled your `input` with classes, just add the `disabled` attribute for your input field

```
{{input type="text" value=firstName class="input-medium" disabledBinding="disabled"}}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Selvaganesh/2pEbR/1/)

Comment: you are absolutely right, I shouldn't post answers soo early in the morning without having coffee first :)

Comment: Like value, now you don't even need disabledBinding. disabled=disabled  is working fine. As a side note, the action should be defined in the controller actions hash. The 'nice' side effect of toggleProperty should now be explicit. see http://jsfiddle.net/2pEbR/4/

Comment: this is definitely a better way :) Another quick question though : I have the logic the other way round - initially my property isEditing is false, so **disabled=isEditing** is back-to-front for me (enabled until I start editing!) . is there a "not" in ember that I can use in this context ? Something like **disabled=!isEditing**

Comment: exactly @sly7_7 ... Have to come out of old conventions

Comment: @Selva-G, have the same feelings about reasing old conventions from my memory, maybe one of these would help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuralyzer :)

Comment: @jmls I think the way you can achieve this is to declare an aliased computed computed property in your controller. something like `disabled: Ember.computed.not('editing')` see http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_not and http://jsfiddle.net/2pEbR/5/